# Linking from one webpage to a specific section on another webpage

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I have two webpages, one is index.html and the other is shop.html.
I am trying to link from shop.html to a section with the Id of #contact in index.html. They both share the same navbar. They are both in the same folder called "Mobile".

This is the code that I am using.
This is the code for the contact link that is on the navbar shared by both pages, but I am trying to accesss it from the shop.html.

```
<li><a href="index.html#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

I have managed to get it to work once, but that was only by right clicking and opening the tab in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works, but you can try:

```
<a href="index.html#contact" target="_blank">Contact</a>
```

This will force it upon opening it in a new tab. However, it should be working only doing

```
    <a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="index.html#contact" target="_blank"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
```

By default, your browser should have `target="_blank"` as shown in the [Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). It may just be an issue with having your list tags wrapped around the anchor tag. If you post the CSS and HTML you are linking to in index.html, I can make sure this works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, turns out it was a jquery smooth scrool animation messing with it.